# Write code SQL INSERT INTO SELECT Statement

Tags: php, sql

I want to insert some values to a table (nilai) from a table (course) if student add new semester like table below

Inside Table nilai

```
|Id_number|Id_student|Class|Semester|Id_Course|SKS|Test_Score|
```

Inside Table Course

```
|Id_Course|Name_Course|Semester|
|A01      |Algorithm  | 1      |
|A02      |C#         | 1      |
|B01      |English    | 2      |
```

this my code

```html
<?php

if (!isset ($_SESSION["Login"]) || $_SESSION ["Login"] != true){
    header ("Location: ../pagenotfound.php");
}
else if ($_SESSION["Id_Usergroup"] = 3){
    $_SESSION ["Login"] = true;
}
else{
    header ("Location: ../pagenotfound.php");
}

?>


$Id_student             = $_POST["Username"];
$Kode_krs_Kelas             = $_POST["Kode_krs_Kelas"];
$ChoseSemester                      = $_POST["ChoseSemester"];

$queaddCh = mysqli_connect($konek, "SELECT Id_course, Semester, SKS FROM Course WHERE Semester ='$ChoseSemester'");
if($queaddCh == false){
    die ("Terjadi Kesalahan : ". mysqli_error($konek));
    }
    while($tambah = mysqli_fetch_array($queaddCh)){
        echo "
            if($add = mysqli_query($konek, 'INSERT INTO nilai (Id_student, Id_course, Semester,SKS_krs,Status) VALUES ('$Id_Student', '$tambah[Id_Course]', $ChoseSemester,'$tambah[SKS]', 'Baru')')){
                header('Location: nilai.php');
                exit();
            }
            die ('Terdapat Kesalahan : '. mysqli_error($konek));

            ";      
    }
```

How do I fix mySQL insert into statement using the select statement to achieve because my session login (Id_student) is not inserted in table nilai ?

Comment: You might need to use INSERT INTO table name FROM table name

Comment: yeah i know but Id_student not insert in Table nilai

Comment: Where should the Id_student value come from? It's not clear. Please give more context to your question and show what you've tried so far. Thanks.

Comment: Id_student come from Login Session

Comment: so pls share table structure of `login` table. And, try to join both to get final result. Sample may be `INSERT INTO table name SELECT s.*,l.* from session s, login l where s.id = l.id`

Comment: You can insert the ID from the session as a static value within the insert...select statement. e.g. `insert into tableX (field1, field 2, field3) select field4, field5, 'staticValue' from tableY`. It will then insert the same static value into all the new rows. Just get your PHP code to add it to the SQL when you're generating the query

Comment: Thanks for the update. Where is `$Id_Student` defined? It's not shown in your code how you populate it. And please, learn about `INSERT...SELECT` as I showed above, you can make this code much more efficient.

Comment: Thank you for ADyson and Koushik Roy i just found the answer

Comment: That's great. You should post it below in the Answers section so other people with similar problems can benefit from it. If they like it they will upvote it and increase your stackoverflow reputation :-)